# What is the difference between laravel method vs trait vs facade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

In a nutshell what would be the easiest way to compare the three?

method vs trait vs facade

Cheers!

Comment: Very broad question… can you precise?

Comment: I mean like a scope - usage etc. In my example I'm trying to understand why one would use Notification method vs Notification trait vs Notifiable Facade for example

Comment: This is not Laravel specific. This is fundamental PHP concepts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They don't really compare because they're really different things.

A method is a function that belongs to a class.

```
class MyClass
{
     public function this_is_a_method() { }
}
```

A trait is a means of sharing code between classes. A trait cannot be instantiated, but rather is included into another class. Both classes and traits can define methods.

```
trait MyTrait
{
     public function this_is_a_method() { }
}
```

Now that I have this trait I can update `MyClass` to use this trait.

```
class MyClass
{
     use MyTrait;
}
```

You can think of traits as copy and paste. Now `MyClass` copies the methods defined in `MyTrait` so you can do this.

```
$class = new MyClass();
$class->this_is_a_method();
```

Both methods and traits are features of PHP. Facades are a feature of Laravel. Facades are simply syntactic sugar to help get services out of the container.

Comment: Cheers @jfadich for a quick explanation! Makes sense!